# Put open and close brackets in document

Tags: brackets

In a Word document I have multiple lines of words one under the other, e.g.:

zignature puppy food

zignature small bites

zinger dog crate

zinger winger dog crate

I want them to automatically generate an open bracket at the start of each line and a close bracket at the end of the line, so they look like these as a result:

[zignature puppy food]

[zignature small bites]

[zinger dog crate]

[zinger winger dog crate]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Quick question: you say you have a word document, does that mean you work in Microsoft Word? If yes, then your question is not suitable for this site, because the site is about LaTeX. Or do you actually have a LaTeX document that you want to ask about?

Comment: Isn't that a task for your favorite editor, rather than TeX? I can think of multiple ways of doing this. Heck, even Word should be able to.

Comment: By the way, it doesn't seem related to (La)TeX, which has nothing to do with Word documents (that aren't plain text, as TeX is).

Comment: Yes it is Word. Does anyone know where or whom to ask then? What if I use notepad then?

Comment: superuser is probably the best fit of the SE sites. https://superuser.com/help/on-topic